# On setting float value in number input with jQuery, the number has comma and I want a dot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my code:

```
<input type="number" id='n'></input>
<button id="set">Set value</button>

$("#set").on("click", function() {
    $("#n").val("1.4");
});
```

here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kcbc701c/9/

When I set the input with jQuery I see "1,4" and my client wants to see "1.4". Is there a way to achieve it without changing the input field to "text"?

Comment: Hey,I saw the fiddle its 1.4 and not 1,4

Comment: Change the browser default language. You see it because your customer's browser is set to a locale in which decimal numbers are shown with a comma instead of a point.

Comment: Just replace the input character with (.) if it is  comma by using keypress or keyup event

Comment: @WilmanPatel bad idea, that will result in _errors_ if the browser is not willing to accept that kind of format for `type=number`

Comment: This actually depends on browser default language. If default language of browser is english, then number will be displayed as 1.4 because decimal separator is dot(.) in english language.  But if language is German or any other language where  decimal separator is comma(,), then comma will be displayed.

Comment: It depends both on language and browser. Some browsers don't support comma as a decimal, so they'll always show a period. Others do support it, in which case it is because of the language. You have to be careful if you want to support `,`, because most browsers will not act like that is a number, so you'd have to make sure to handle all the logic yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason likely has to do with browser default language.

In some countries, using a dot for a decimal (e.g., `1.4`) is the norm. In other countries, using a comma for a decimal is the norm (e.g., `1,4`).

In the case of  `<input type="number" />`, the browser is going to use whatever makes sense for the current user's browser.

So, you have a couple of ways to deal with this:

- Specifically set the language in the `<html>` tag or directly on the `<input>` tags. You can use something like `<input type="number" lang="en-150" />`
- Stop using `type="number"`. While this isn't a great approach, if you treat it like a normal input and handle the logic yourself, there is no guesswork or possible browser incompatibility.

This blog has a really good write-up on this if you want more information: [HTML5 number inputs](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/html5-input-number-localization#impl-notes)